# Displaying a date Short Format

Tags: c#

I am Trying to show a date in a textbox with short format, i get the data from the database.

At presentation Time I want it to be shown with another Format Than this

> dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss AM/PM

How can I do it?

Where I want it to be shown:

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Clear()
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", n.ADataSet, "Table.date")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to the below... note that this overload allows you to specify a format ("yyyy-MM-dd") in the last parameter.

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", n.ADataSet, "Table.date", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Inside the database it has rhis format:

No, inside the database it will be stored in some binary format. Fundamentally, it's a date - it's not in any particular format, any more than a number is stored in decimal or hex... it's just a date.

When you fetch the value, you're getting a `DateTime`. Again, that's not got any particular format - it's just a date and time. You need to format it at *presentation* time.

If you look at the documentation for [`ControlBindingsCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlbindingscollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see an example with custom formatting.

Comment: i will try to use that info in future projects